# PL embedding of 3-manifold PL triangulation into 5-manifold PL triangulation

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Are there any PL triangulations of closed orientable 3-manifolds that do not PL-embed into some PL triangulation of a closed 5-manifold?

Comment: How are you quantifyiing the 5-manifold(s)?

Answer (score 1):

In dimension 3, existence and uniqueness of PL/smooth structures imply every PL manifold comes from a smooth manifold via passing to the Whitehead triangulation. This reduces the question to whether smooth 3-manifolds embed into 5 dimensional space (or alternatively the 5-sphere). In an aptly named [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-71/issue-3.P1/All-3-manifolds-imbed-in-5-space/bams/1183526924.full), Wall proves that they do.